# Require shopware 6 plugin via composer

Tags: plugins, composer-php, shopware6

I am developing a custom plugin for Shopware 6. It will not be sitting in Shopware Store but our own company repo on github.

How can I make it get installed into `custom/plugins` instead of `vendor` when I run `composer require plugin/name`?

I tried setting up in plugin's composer `"type": "shopware-plugin"` and `"type": "shopware-platform-plugin"` but it still puts it into `vendor`.

There is this: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md - I would rather specify a correct type instead of setting up an install path manually using `installer-paths`.

Do you know what each shopware type means?

My composer version is 1.10.8

Comment: Did you tagged new version after changing `type` in `composer.json` of your plugin?

Comment: No, for development I am using linking towards the branch `dev-my-branch` along with setting up a proper entry in `repositories` key to point toward vcs url.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Turns out that as of today (2020.07.07) composer installers is unable to handle `shopware-platform-plugin` types. I ended up making a custom installer that you can find here: https://github.com/radixs/composer-shopware6-installer - just add it to your plugin's composer and done.

---

I found what is wrong. I got confused with other guides that explain how to create custom installer and did not notice that when using default installers - they are not included in composer, they need to be required in the plugin:

```
    "require": {
        "shopware/core": "*",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
```

I feel silly, not deleting it in case there are more *geniuses* like me out there.