# composer.json file configuraton to install Shopware 6 plugins in custom/plugins directory

Tags: plugins, composer-php, shopware

[Require shopware 6 plugin via composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265181/require-shopware-6-plugin-via-composer/64594821#64594821)

Following up on this question and answer. I wondered what else anyone has added to install a plugin into `custom/plugin` for Shopware 6? I removed my `composer.lock` and the `vendor` and `var/cache` directories. I and trying to do the same thing, and I have required `composer/installers` to my plugin `composer.json` file and added:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "custom/plugins": ["type:shopware-platform-plugin"]
    }
}
```

to the root `composer.json` but it is still putting my plugin into the vendor directory. Any suggestions would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want that the plugin is installed into `custom/plugins` in the first place?

From a technical point of view it doesn't matter whether your plugin is located in `vendor` or in `custom/plugins` it should work in both location.

Comment: Thanks, @j_effering. Initially, I thought it would be more "aesthetically" pleasing, as I am new to Shopware 6 and have mainly worked with Concrete5 I thought I would try to replicate the same behaviour of using `composer require` or `composer update` to install packages in the `concrete5_root/public/packages` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any installers or other tools for installing plugins via composer.

If you have placed your plugin in `custom/plugins` (in case you are using the [development template](https://github.com/shopware/development/blob/master/composer.json#L6-L12)) or in `custom/static-plugins` (in case you are using the [production template](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/6.3/composer.json#L37-L45)/zip installation) your plugin will be symlinked to your root vendor directory, if you `composer require` your plugin.

For Shopware 6 it doesn't matter where your plugin is located.

If you don't like the behaviour, that your plugins are symlinked, you can simply remove the repository configuration from the root `composer.json`. Above I have linked the positions you need to change.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelT, I was trying to treat Shopware 6 as I would concrete5. Also, I thought this might have been the root of my problem, which was when I added my plugin in the root `composer,json` and used `composer require` it kept complaining about the template configuration "tab" field. But I managed to fix this last night. As you said, it doesn't matter where the plugin is located as I was able to install, activate and change the theme. Thanks again for your clear explanation.